# Sharepoint 2007 library not showing files and folders in it

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

We have a shared documents library in SharePoint 2007 environment we are not able to view the items in the library all items view. The account has full control permission. and able to view items in content and structure from site settings. but not able to view items inside the library.

Please help me with this.

Comment: How many files in Doc Lib? what about other users can see these files?

Comment: It has around 1800 files, no one able to see the file.
Another library which has more than 5000 files is working fine. I guess its not about the number of files.